# I almost got the Schwarzschild solution

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, black-holes, differential-geometry, metric-tensor

I was trying to derive the Schwarzschild metric, but i got the following solution:

$$ds^2=(C_1-\frac{1}{r})dt^2-\frac{1}{(C_1-\frac{1}{r})}dr^2-r^2d\Omega^2.$$

The correct place for the $C_1$ should be multiplying $r$, because in this case, I would be able to compare with the Newtonian limit:

$$g_{00}=1-\frac{2Gm}{c^2r}.$$

Is my solution wrong? Is there any coordinate transformation that put my answer in the proper form?

Comment: Try scaling the variable $r$ by a constant.

Answer (score 1):

Try $C_1 = \frac{c^2}{2mG}$ and redefine coordinates $r$ and $t$ in order to rescale $C_1$ (e. g., $C_1 dt^2 = dT^2$, $g_{rr}dr^2=g_{RR}dR^2$, $g_{RR}= \frac{1}{1-\frac{2Gm}{c^2 R}}$).

Comment: This would mess up the angular part of the metric!

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is wrong. If you calculate the Ricci tensor of your solution you find

$$R = (1-C_1)d\Omega^2$$

hence it is only a solution to the vacuum Einstein equation when $C_1=1$.

Comment: You are completely right !! Thank you a lot, mmeent. I will try to solve it again.